# ajax не возвращает результат на страницу

Tags: javascript, ajax

ajax не возвращает результат на страницу, хотя сам скрипт работает...  В консоли и при отладке никаких ошибок не наблюдаю

```
// Часть файла обработчика ajax_upl_preview на php
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path . $name)) {
        // Далее можно сохранить название файла в БД и т.п.
        $success = '<p style="color: green">Файл «' . $name . '» успешно загружен.</p>';
    } else {
        $error = 'Не удалось загрузить файл.';
    }
// получение сообщения о результате загрузки файла (результат)
if (!empty($error)) {
    $error = '<p style="color: red">' . $error . '</p>';  
}
 
$data = array(
    'error'   => $error,
    'success' => $success,
);
 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit();




//часть файла index.html

<input type='file' id='js-file' class='accent slim small button'accept='image/jpeg,image/png '>
 <div id='result'></div> 

 <script>
$("#js-file").change(function(){
  if (window.FormData === undefined) {
    alert('В вашем браузере FormData не поддерживается')
  } else {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $("#js-file")[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/ajax_upl_preview',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function(msg){
        if (msg.error == '') {
          $("#js-file").hide();
          $('#result').html(msg.success);
        } else {
          $('#result').html(msg.error);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: А что возвращает? А где обработчик ошибок?